# how to access a blueprint component with an Unreal pawn character spawned from the player start set up in the game mode?

Tags: unreal-engine4, game-development, unreal-blueprint

I'm kind off a beginner, I was following the tutorial in the unreal documentation for direct blueprint communication, my problem is the following:  when I set up a character blueprint so it accesses another blueprint with an object reference I want it so when my character is spawned that instance of my character is able to access the referenced object, currently it generates an error that pretty much says that that particular instance of my character is not the one that has the object reference variable set up, it only lets me assign it to characters in my scene yet these ones aren't the ones that are used to play when I hit play in the editor, the one used to play is set up so it's spawned by the game mode. thought this is probably not the way I would find it very useful to know a workaround to this.

Comment: The player that you spawn using the player start should have an index of zero

Comment: index of 0, got it. mmh gess they don't specify that in the direct blueprint communication unreal docs. thak you

Answer (score 1):

#### C++

You can use `GetComponentsByClass` in `BeginPlay()`, e.g.:

```
TArray<UActorComponent*> Comps1 = 
GetComponentsByClass(UStaticMeshComponent::StaticClass());
```

Or you can add tags in specified Component, and use `GetComponentsByTag`:
[image]

```
TArray<UActorComponent*> Comps2 = GetComponentsByTag(UStaticMeshComponent::StaticClass(), FName(TEXT("t1")));
```

They worked both for Blueprint Component and Native Component.

#### Blueprint

If there's only one character in level, you can use `Get Actor of Class`.
[image]

If there'are more than one characters, you can use `Get All Actors of Class` and foreach them.
[image]

Comment: thank you, so instead of casting or getting an object reference i shall use that. i don't know how to do it by c++ , yet i will try to figure it out in blueprints. if anything don't you know some tutorial that explains this sort of thing? or usually every tutorial on this subject does it by explaining how to do it in the level blueprint. anyways thank you.

Comment: @AndresMauricioRojasMarquez Hi, I have update the answer for blueprint method, you can try again, thanks. You'd better watch the offical  video tutorials on Youtube, they're very useful for beginner.

Comment: [Unreal Engine 4 Blueprints Tutorial Series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BVpy7kvz_yg&list=PLL0cLF8gjBpqRUy7r0DtVY3Fcdgq5Wk-h)